# VIM: Search for next function call using tags file

Tags: vim

Is it possible to access VIM's tags-file from Vimscript?

I have a function that searches for what looks like function calls (using a regular expression).
I'd like to confirm that these are really functions by searching the tags file.

Note that I'm looking for function *calls* and not function declarations.

[This is for navigating long files of Matlab code, by the way]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `taglist()` function provides access to the tags Vim knows about from its tags file(s).

Note that tags files by themselves cannot find function calls; but you appear to know that, since you're talking about finding calls yourself and verifying with tags that what you've found actually is a function.